# Trying to use react-materialize component in Gatsby.js, get ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, reactjs, materialize, gatsby

I have a gatsby project and I am trying to use react-materialize, the parallax component. It compiles but i get ReferenceError: $ is not defined when I try to use a parallax component.

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Parallax.componentDidMount
C:/Users/Albert/Documents/Albert Site/v2/node_modules/react-materialize/lib/Parallax.js:41
  38 | _createClass(Parallax, [{
  39 |   key: 'componentDidMount',
  40 |   value: function componentDidMount() {
> 41 |     $('.parallax').parallax();
  42 |   }
  43 | }, {
  44 |   key: 'render',
```

Also materialize-css doesn't work as intended. I tried to intiailize materialize-css components in javascript in my componentdidmount() function and that didn't work properly either.

Here is how I am using it:

pages/index.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import 'jquery'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'
import { Parallax } from 'react-materialize'
import city from '../assets/city.png'
import city2 from '../assets/city.jpg'

class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section className="section">
        <div>
          <Parallax imageSrc={city} />
          <div className="section white">
            <h2>Parallax</h2>
            <p>hellloooooo</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default IndexPage
```

layout/index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import y from '../assets/y.png'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min.js'
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css'
import './index.css'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to import jquery funnily

from

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

to

```
import $ from 'jquery/src/jquery'
```

from https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/679#issuecomment-311887619

Answer (score 0):

import $ from 'jquery'

Refrence : https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery

And initialize it in componentWillMount()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.parallax').parallax();
});
```

Comment: what error is showing if you are adding this line `import $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: the same error as the original post, nothing changes

Comment: initialize it in componentWillMount()

Comment: Is it possible to do it with vanillaJS instead of jQuery?